# ROS Navigation Stack, Hydro and Indigo

Tags: ros, navigation, ros-hydro, stack, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there any difference between ROS Navigation Stack in Hydro and Indigo?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/190298/ros-navigation-stack,-hydro-and-indigo/) by [ROSCMBOT](https://answers.ros.org/users/16861/roscmbot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 651 on 2014-08-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No. They are both made off of the hydro_devel branch.

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2014-08-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2